# In Vim, how can I make Esc and arrow keys work in insert mode?

Tags: vim, tmux

Terminals send the arrow keys as sequences which begin with `Esc`.  In Vim, there's an option `'esckeys'` which lets keys which begin with `Esc` work in insert mode.  It does this at the expense of the actual `Esc` key responding immediately, because Vim no longer knows if you're just pressing `Esc` or beginning to spell an arrow key.

**Here's what I'd like to be able to do in insert mode:**

1. Press an arrow key and have the cursor go in that direction, and
2. Press `Esc` and leave insert mode immediately.

I've got the beginnings of a solution.  Even with `:set noesckeys`, I can still map a key to `<Up>` like so:

```
imap q <Up>
```

Of course, `q` is not a good key to make the cursor go up.  Instead, I'd like to map my arrow keys my terminal emulator to something that doesn't start with `Esc` (like some random Unicode characters I'll never type) and then `imap` those to the directions in Vim.

The problem is this: when I leave Vim, my arrow keys will stop working.  Only Vim knows what they mean now.

I'm working inside tmux inside iTerm2.  Is there a way to make a binding like this live in only one tmux pane?  Or make Vim inform tmux that it should use the crazy arrow key bindings while it's running?  Any other ideas?

(Incidentally, I'd be happy to just not use arrow keys in insert mode at all myself, but I pair with people who expect them to work, and I want to be a courteous pair.)

Comment: What terminal are you using? In gnome terminal, xterm, and OSX's terminal my arrow keys work exactly as you would expect in insert mode with vim running inside tmux.

Comment: I'm using iTerm2.  Arrow keys do work, but only with `set esckeys`.  I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `ttimeoutlen` (note: two leading `t`s, not one) to very small value. Something like 10 milliseconds, but it may work even with zero. With any positive ttimeoutlen you will have almost immediate exit (it will wait for that amount of milliseconds), with it set to zero it should be immediate (meaning that it would not wait for arrow keys to complete at all: either the whole sequence is in stdin buffer and it is considered to be an arrow key or not and it is considered to be a sequence of independent characters). I have 100 milliseconds and fail to notice this timeout.

Comment: See also https://github.com/matze/vim-move/issues/15#issuecomment-168177827

Answer (score 8):

What is your problem exactly? Do your arrow keys work in Vim or not? Do they work in tmux or not?

I've had a problem with arrow keys displaying control characters (`[A`,`[B`…) in Vim/tmux once, I solved it by adding

```
nnoremap <Esc>A <up>
nnoremap <Esc>B <down>
nnoremap <Esc>C <right>
nnoremap <Esc>D <left>
inoremap <Esc>A <up>
inoremap <Esc>B <down>
inoremap <Esc>C <right>
inoremap <Esc>D <left>
```

to my `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: They do work, with `set esckeys`, but I want to have `Esc` take me out of insert mode immediately, which it can't do with `esckeys`, because Vim doesn't know if I'm just pressing `Esc` or starting to spell an arrow key.  I've clarified the question.

Comment: I don't have `set esckeys`. The mappings above are defined specifically to provide arrow navigation without `esckeys`. If you insist on using `set esckeys`, `:help esckeys` gives you the answer to your question (`timeoutlen`).

Comment: My question is: how can I use arrow keys in insert mode and have `Esc` take me out of insert mode *immediately* (without a timeout).

Comment: `set noesckeys` means arrows not working in CLI Vim and `set esckeys` means arrows working in CLI Vim. Did you read `:help esckeys` and my comment? Set `timeoutlen` (default 1000 milliseconds) to a small value like 200 and you will get exactly what you want but it will have some drawbacks: long commands will probably be a bit harder to type.

Comment: Right, I get how it's supposed to work.  I'm trying to hack around it so I *can* use arrow keys in with `noesckeys`, by encoding the arrow keys as something that doesn't start with `Esc`.

Comment: @romainl You are suggesting something strange. Just the same help topic you pointed out tells that everything will be solved if `'ttimeoutlen'` will be set to small value. I have it equal to `100` milliseconds, but on my desktop and router (accessed through ssh) even `ttimeoutlen=0` works (meaning that it would not wait for arrow keys to complete at all: either the whole sequence is in stdin buffer and it is considered to be an arrow key or not and it is a sequence of independent characters).

Comment: @Peeja Just set `ttimeoutlen` (note: two leading `t`s, not one) to very small value. Something like `10` milliseconds, but it may work even with zero. With any positive `ttimeoutlen` you will have *almost* immediate exit (it will wait for that amount of milliseconds), with it set to zero it should be immediate. I have `100` milliseconds and fail to notice this timeout.

Comment: @ZyX That's the best answer. If you want to write it up as an answer to the question, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If someone using windows 10 comes here, I can tell you what worked for me.
:set term=ansi

You can put that in your .vimrc file or just set it in the editor to see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me: add the following lines to your .vimrc file (type Ctrl-V and press cursor up for ^[OA ...):

```
 set t_ku=^[OA
 set t_kd=^[OB
 set t_kr=^[OC
 set t_kl=^[OD
```